# Sum element is array returning wrong value

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a switch button called Today and yesterday. I have an array of values. When I click today it should sum the array values in today and when I click yesterday it should add today and yesterday value and display.

I am facing a problem, that I stated below

```
public val1;
public val2;
public val3;
public val4;
data = [];

if (value == 'a') {
  val1 = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + Number(cur)); // add values inside 
  array
} else if (value == 'b') {
  val2 = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + Number(cur));
} else if (value == 'c') {
  val3 = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + Number(cur));
} else if (value == 'd') {
  val4 = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + Number(cur));
}
this.data.push(this.val1, this.val2, this.val3, this.val4);
```

**finally**

`arr = [5, undefined, 5,5]`
`arr = [15,10,25,10]`

When I click today, Its showing `[5, undefined, 5,5]` which is correct
When I click yesterday, Its Showing `[20,10,30,15]` (today + yesterday) which is correct. When I click **today** again its showing  `[5, 10, 5,5]` // 10 got append from the previous array but other values don't. My expected o/p is  `[5, undefined, 5,5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
val1=null;
val2=null;
val3=null;
val4=null;
```

before first if, and expect `null` instead of `undefied`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects hold a reference to an object, so the best way to solve the problem is to assign **null** value before iterating the process.